# Python always gives me a ImportError

Tags: python, django, import

I have two directories, which are bumblebee.new and bumblebee.
`bumblebee.new/bumblebee/app.py` wants to import some files from `bumblebee/bumblebee`.
At the beginning, I met an `ImportError: No module named bumblebee`. After I added `bumblebee/bumblebee` into syspath, it became:

```
File "app.py", line 12, in <module>
    from bumblebee import botqueueapi
  File "/root/bumblebee/bumblebee/bumblebee.py", line 23, in <module>
    import botqueueapi
  File "/root/bumblebee.new/bumblebee/botqueueapi.py", line 12, in <module>
    from bumblebee import hive
ImportError: cannot import name hive
```

How to solve these problems? Why cannot import in these files?
Thank you for you suggestions and advice!

Answer (score 1):

Python's import system is a bit messy and therefore you can get name clashes: you are using "bumblebee" three times in that project which is confusing for Python. The import "from bumblebee import hive" is now interpreted at the top-level module and not as the local file. This means it's trying to import "hive" from a different location than you expect and it can't find it there.

Two rules of thumb:

- Always run a Python project from the top-level directory. So "python full/path/to/my/file.py"
- Always write the import in full, so "from full.path.to.my.file import foo" as opposed to "from file import foo".

Now, you don't have to follow these rules but you have to know what you're doing in that case. The above rules should avoid name clashes.

Comment: But it still does not work. Below is the imports                                                      import curses
import hashlib
import json
import logging
import stacktracer
import threading
import time
import Queue


import sys
sys.path.insert(1,'/root/bumblebee/bumblebee')
from bumblebee import workerbee
from bumblebee import camera_contol
from bumblebee import hive
from bumblebee import botqueueapi                                        I have renamed bumblebee file in bumblebee.new into bumblebeenew. But still cannot.

Comment: Sorry for the messy imports. what I understand is that, from bumblebee import XX is to import from bumblebee/bumblebee, which is a new path I added into sys.path. SO there were two bumblebee files. I renamed the new one, why still cannot?

Comment: @user3917757 you have to make sure "from bumblebee" is unambiguous and that Python knows what module to import. So you have to change the imports as above to make sure that doesn't happen.